# Is there any option in snowflake to save or load worksheets?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any option in snowflake to save or load worksheets?

Or to download worksheet to local and load it from local?

(I don't mean such option as paste it via clipboard to some text editor and save.)

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake automatically saves your worksheet. You can also load a script from your local to a worksheet. However there is no way to download worksheet

```
Saved worksheets are not accessible outside of the Snowflake web interface.
Saved worksheets cannot currently be shared with other users.
```

For more information, please look at

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html

Answer (score 0):

worksheets are saved in @~/worksheet_data/[uuid]. If you know when the sheet you are interested in was last modified, you could do something like

```
list @~/worksheet_data ;
get @~/worksheet_data/123-sdf-1-sdfa file:///tmp/ ;
```

to locally get that worksheet

Comment: Nice thinking but the file is encrypted in md5, each with a different key, have you tried to decrypt it?

Comment: From https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html#backing-up-your-own-worksheets - the new SnowSight UI stores worksheets in a different location (doesn't say where they are).  My list of worksheet_data is empty in SnowSight UI.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on Said's answer, worksheets are saved in "user stage"

If you like to get all worksheets you can do it programmatically,

After you run the list command

`list @~/worksheet_data;`

Get the names of worksheets with

`select name FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))`

iterate through name column in your choice of scripting language and download the worksheets

`get @~/worksheet_data/<name> file:///<your local location> ;`

Comment: What about decrypting the files? it is downloaded in md5 each with different key as in the result of the LIST command? any thought about it?