# How to export Snowflake Web UI Worksheet SQL to file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Classic Snowflake Web UI and the new Snowsight are great at importing sql from a file but neither allows you to **export** sql to a file. Is there a workaround?

[image: Snowsight Worksheet Menu]

Answer (score 1):

The query pane is interactive so the obvious workaround will be:

```
CTRL + A (select all)
CTRL + C (copy)
<open_favourite_text_editor>
CTRL + P (paste)
CTRL + S (save)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not the solution I was hoping for. Sounds like this lack of the feature is by design; Snowflake wants users to use their tool yet not make it easy to export your SQL :-(

Answer (score 1):

This tool can help you while the team develops a native feature to export worksheets:

- "Snowflake Snowsight Extensions wrap Snowsight features that do not have API or SQL alternatives, such as manipulating Dashboards and Worksheets, and retrieving Query Profile and step timings."

  - https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions

Further explained on this post:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/importing-and-exporting-snowsight-dashboards-and-worksheets-3cd8e34d29c8

For example, to save to a file within PowerShell:

```sh
PS > $dashboards | foreach {$_.SaveToFolder(“path/to/folder”)}
PS > $dashboards[0].SaveToFile(“path/to/folder/mydashboard.json”)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IDE to connect to snowflake and write queries. Then the scripts can be downloaded using IDE features and can sync with git repo as well.

dbeaver is one such IDE which supports snowflake :
https://hevodata.com/learn/dbeaver-snowflake/

Comment: Thanks! I use SQL Assistant and DBeaver with an ODBC connection to Snowflake where you can save SQL scripts to a file. Just was curious if I was missing a function of the Web UI.--sounds like this is by design; Snowflake wants users to use their tool yet not make it easy to export your SQL :-(

Answer (score 0):

ETA: I'm adding this edit to the front because this is what actually worked.

Again, BSON was a dead end & punycode is irrelevant. I don't know why punycode is referenced in the metadata file; but my best guess is that they might use punycode to encode the worksheet name itself (though I'm not sure why that would be needed since it shouldn't need to be part of a URL).

After doing terrible things and trying a number of complex ways of dealing with escape character hell, I found that the actual encoding is very simple. It just works as an 8 bit encoding with anything that might cause problems escaped away (null, control codes, double quotes, etc.). To load, treat the file as a text file using an 8-bit encoding; extract the data as a JSON field, then re-encode that extracted data as that same encoding. I just used latin_1 to read; but it may not even matter which encoding you use as long as you are consistent and use the same one to re-encode. The encoded field will then be valid zlib compressed data.

I decided that I wanted to start from scratch so I needed to back the worksheets first and I made a Python script based on my findings above. Be warned that this may return even worksheets that you previously closed for good. After running this and verifying that backups were created, I just ran `rm @~/worksheet_data/;`, closed the tab & reopened it.

Here's the code (fill in the appropriate base directory location):

```
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
import configparser
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, exc
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
import pathlib
import json
import zlib
import string

def format_filename(s: str) -> str: # From https://gist.github.com/seanh/93666
    """Take a string and return a valid filename constructed from the string.
Uses a whitelist approach: any characters not present in valid_chars are
removed. Also spaces are replaced with underscores.
 
Note: this method may produce invalid filenames such as ``, `.` or `..`
When I use this method I prepend a date string like '2009_01_15_19_46_32_'
and append a file extension like '.txt', so I avoid the potential of using
an invalid filename.
 
"""
    valid_chars = "-_.() %s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
    filename = ''.join(c for c in s if c in valid_chars)
    # filename = filename.replace(' ','_') # I don't like spaces in filenames.
    return filename

def trlng_dash(s: str) -> str:
    """Removes trailing character if present."""
    return s[:-1] if s[-1] == '-' else s


sso_authenticate = True

# Assumes CLI config file exists.
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

home = pathlib.Path.home()
config_loc = home/'.snowsql/config' # Assumes it's set up from Snowflake CLI.
base_dir = home/r'{your Desired base directory goes here.}'
json_dir = base_dir/'json' # Location for your worksheet stage JSON files.
sql_dir = base_dir/'sql'   # Location for your worksheets.

# Assumes CLI config file exists.
config.read(config_loc)

# Add connection parameters here (assumes CLI config exists).
# Using sso so only 2 are needed.
# If there's no config file, etc. enter by hand here (or however you want to do it).
connection_params = {
        'account': config['connections']['accountname'],
        'user': config['connections']['username'],
}

if sso_authenticate:
    connection_params['authenticator'] = 'externalbrowser'
if config['connections'].get('password', None) is not None:
    connection_params['password'] = config['connections']['password']
if config['connections'].get('rolename', None) is not None:
    connection_params['role'] = config['connections']['rolename']
if locals().get('database', None) is not None:
    connection_params['database'] = database
if locals().get('schema', None) is not None:
    connection_params['schema'] = schema

sf_engine = create_engine(URL(**connection_params))



if not base_dir.exists():
    base_dir.mkdir()
if not json_dir.exists():
    json_dir.mkdir()
if not (sql_dir).exists():
    sql_dir.mkdir()

with sf_engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(f'get @~/worksheet_data/ \'file://{str(json_dir.as_posix())}\';')

for file in [path for path in json_dir.glob('*') if path.is_file()]:
    if file.suffix != '.json':
        file.replace(file.with_suffix(file.suffix + '.json'))

with open(json_dir/'metadata.json', 'r') as metadata_file:
    files_meta = json.load(metadata_file)

# List of files from metadata file will contain some empty worksheets.
files_description_orig = OrderedDict((file_key_value['name'], file_key_value) for file_key_value in sorted(files_meta['activeWorksheets'] + list(files_meta['inactiveWorksheets'].values()), key=lambda x: x['name']) if file_key_value['name']) 
# files_description will only track non empty worksheets
files_description = files_description_orig.copy()


# Create updated files description filtering out empty worksheets.
for item in files_description_orig:
    json_file = json_dir/f"{files_description_orig[item]['name']}.json"
    
    # If a file didn't make it or was deleted by hand, we should
    # remove from the filtered description & continue to the next item.
    if not (json_file.exists() and json_file.is_file()):
        del files_description[item]
        continue
    with open(json_file, 'r', encoding='latin_1') as f:
        json_dat = json.load(f)
        # If the file represents a worksheet with a body field, we want it.
        if not json_dat['wsContents'].get('body'):
            del files_description[item]
        ## Delete JSON files corresponsing to empty worksheets.
        #     f.close()
        #     try:
        #         (json_dir/f"{files_description_orig[item]['name']}.json").unlink()
        #     except:
        #         pass

# Produce a list of normalized filenames (no illegal or awkward characters).
file_names = set(
    format_filename(trlng_dash(files_description[item]['encodedDetails']['scriptName']).strip())
    for item in files_description)

# Add useful information to our files_description OrderedDict
for file_name in file_names:
    repeats_cnt = 0
    file_name_repeats = (
        item
        for item
        in files_description
        if file_name == format_filename(trlng_dash(files_description[item]['encodedDetails']['scriptName']).strip())
    )
    for file_uuid in file_name_repeats:
        files_description[file_uuid]['normalizedName'] = file_name
        files_description[file_uuid]['stemSuffix'] = '' if repeats_cnt == 0 else f'({repeats_cnt:0>2})'
        repeats_cnt += 1

# Now we iterate on non-empty worksheets only.
for item in files_description:
    json_file = json_dir/f"{files_description[item]['name']}.json"
    with open(json_file, 'r', encoding='latin_1') as f:
        json_dat = json.load(f)
        body = json_dat['wsContents']['body']
        body_bin = body.encode('latin_1')
        body_txt = zlib.decompress(body_bin).decode('utf8')
        sql_file = sql_dir/f"{files_description[item]['normalizedName']}{files_description[item]['stemSuffix']}.sql"
        with open(sql_file, 'w') as sql_f:
            sql_f.write(body_txt)
        creation_stamp = files_description[item]['created']/1000
        os.utime(sql_file, (creation_stamp,creation_stamp))
print('Done!')
```

---

As mentioned at [Is there any option in snowflake to save or load worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574808/is-there-any-option-in-snowflake-to-save-or-load-worksheets) (and in Snowflake's own documentation), in the Classic UI, the worksheets are saved at the user stage under `@~/worksheet_data/`.

You can download it with a get command like:
`get @~/worksheet_data/<name> file:///<your local location>;` (though you might need quoting if running from Windows).

The problem is that I do not know how to access it programmatically. The downloaded files look like JSON but it is not valid JSON. The main key is "wsContents" and contains most of the worksheet information. Its value includes two subkeys, "encoding" and "body".

The "encoding" key denotes that gzip is being used. The "body" key seems to be the actual worksheet data which looks a lot like a straight binary representation of the compressed text data. As such, any JSON reader will choke on it.

If it is anything like that, I do not currently know how to access it programmatically using Python.

I do see that a JSON like format exists, BSON, that is bundled into PyMongo. Trying to use this on these files fails. I even tried `bson.is_valid` and it returns `False` so I am assuming that it means that these files in Snowflake are not actually BSON.

---

Edited to add: Again, BSON is a dead end.

Examining the "body" value as just binary data, the first two bytes of sample files do seem to correspond to default zlib compression (0x789c). However, attempting to run straight zlib.decompress on the slice created from that first byte to the last corresponding to the first & last characters of the "body" value results in the error:

```
Error - 3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set
```

This makes me think that the bytes there, as is, are at least partly garbage and still need some processing before they can be decompressed.

One clue that I failed to mention earlier is that the metadata file (called "metadata" and which serves as an inventory of the remaining files at the `@~/worksheet_data/` location) declares that the files use the punycode encoding. However, I have not known how to use that information. The data in these files doesn't particularly look like what I feel punycode should look like nor does it particularly make sense to me that you would use punycode on binary data that is not meant to ever be used to directly generate text such as zlib compressed data.